# Mailslots in Python

Tags: python, ipc

Hello is there any good tutorial / doc. for using the Win MailSlots in Python ?

Comment: This is the number one Google hit for "Mailslot in Python" and it's basically just a link from three years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/winsys/mailslots.html